# What is the best oxidizer?

Tags: oxygen

I was wondering if there is a more efficient alternative to plain o2? Also, I know this is adding another question, but could you make a functioning rocket with ozone(O3) as an oxidizer(if it is denser than O2(and if you could liquify it.))? I'm talking about somehow breaking apart the oxygen atoms Before They Reach The Reaction Chamber.

Comment: related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20527/there-are-better-oxidizer-than-oxygen

Comment: Not just related, a duplicate.

Comment: And the answer depends very much on what one means by "better". There are many, many good reasons why we don't see rockets with fluorine as the oxidizer even though several metrics appear to indicate that fluorine is a far superior oxidizer than is oxygen.

Comment: Yeah, oxygen seems to be the best oxidizer being one that provides good specific energy, products of combustion are mostly harmless and it doesn't oxidize an excessive number of materials. Fluorine compounds provide superior energy but don't necessarily discriminate between what's fuel and what's engine. And you'd better mark the launchpad as a massive toxic spill site after each launch.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you consider rewriting your question to ask specifically about ozone and then vote to re-open, but it turns out that that has been asked and answered before as well! [Using ozone as oxidizer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19498/12102)

Comment: @SF. "but don't necessarily discriminate between what's fuel and what's engine." that is not only valid for fluorine, it may be true for oxygen too.