# How stable is ozone as a compressed gas?

Tags: fuel, oxidizer

I have heard that liquid ozone is violently unstable, making it unusable in any meaningful concentrations. Would using it as a compressed gas partially solves the problem? What is the mechanism of its breakdown? I assume it heats up when breaking down to O2 and the flashing into gas blows up the rocket. Is it a runaway reaction, meaning once it starts breaking down it doesn't stop until its all O2 and blows you up or is it more of a random breakdown that is hard to predict and therefore handle? If its not a runaway reaction then how violently does it convert to O2 and how much has been observed at most for a set period of time?

Comment: Highly relevant, possible duplicate https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19498/6944

Comment: Based on answers to the other question it sounds like the spaceflight community have given up on exploring ozone as a rocket fuel. That suggests that there may not be specific answers to your questions from spaceflight knowledge. However, [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place to explore stability issues of ozone, things that trigger it to dissociate (explode) (container walls, contaminants) and things that can stabilize it against that.

Comment: Read Wikipedia about [ozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone) It is not stable at all as compressed gas. It may condensed to a liquid, but it should not warm to its boiling point, it may explode then. So it could neither be stored as a liquid nor  as compressed gas, usage for space is impossible, It reacts with all metals useful for rockets construction.